# Relationship between two lines

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is $x-y-1=0$ and $x-y+1=0$
So far, as finding $k$ for both lines is one, and so it is parallel. But having the rule of $b1 \neq b2$, can it still be a parallel? Because their $b$ is $1$. They have the same

Can someone help me? I don't know how to determine this one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One "$b$" is $+1$, while the other is $-1$. These are distinct parallel lines.

Comment: so the sign matters? i thought just the number alone lol

Comment: It *does* matter! You wrote that the two lines have the same slope ($k$), hence they are parallel. Now, either they are distinct parallel lines, or they are the same line. To decide, check the ordinate at origin, that is $y$ when $x=0$, for one line it's $+1$, and for the other it's $-1$. So they are not the same line.

Comment: Oh, i understand now. Thanks a lot!